# React P tag update but not live

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I do not want the p tag to be updated live.
When i write in the input p tag automatically update.
**i want update when i click ok button and not live mode.**
What I write in the input directly updates the p tag. I do not want that

This is code --->

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'


class Test extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            text:"hello",
            
        }
        this.alpha=this.alpha.bind(this)
        this.show=this.show.bind(this)

    }
    alpha(event){
        this.setState({text:event.target.value})
    }
    show(){
        alert(this.state.text)
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <input type="text"  onChange={this.alpha} />
                <button onClick={this.show} >ok</button>
                <p>{this.state.text}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'


class Test extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state={
            text: '',
            value: 'hello',
        }

        this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.apply=this.apply.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    }

    apply(){
      this.setState(({ value }) => ({ text: value }));
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <button onClick={this.apply}>ok</button>
                <p>{this.state.text}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Test
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
 13 line

Comment: @lissettdm know you?

Comment: @kokiwebaaa, :) I don't know, you tell me ;)

Comment: While this may fix the problem I would have loved to see an explanation why the questions code is not working as intended and what was done to fix it. Stackoverflow is used to help understand (and of course fix) problems, but not just the latter.

Comment: Updated. Just forgot to rename methods in the constructor.